# Instead of Update trigger Performance Issue

Tags: oracle, performance, triggers, sql-update

I developed a trigger on oracle for my application to direct all updates of a view to the table above.

however, this leads to performance problems.

here the trigger

```
create or replace trigger trg_triggerview
instead of update
on view_based_on_table
begin
   - ------------------------------------
   if (: new.transfer_counter_column_view is not null) then
     update table t
     set transfer_counter_column_table =: new.transfer_counter_column_view 
     where t.id =: old.id;
   end if;
   -
end;
/

old trigger trg_triggerview ENABLE
;
```

transfer_counter_column_view of the view based on the transfer_counter_column_table of the table.

the id is the same in the table as in the view.

that's why the where clauses is filtered for id.

the transfer counter is updated up to 300 times per minute on client-side

did anybody knows a performant solution for this?

Comment: can you provide the code of the view ? how many indexes do you have in the underlying table ?

Comment: can you provide the explain plan of the update statement ?

Comment: about 15 indexes are configured on the table

Comment: it would be great to have the explain plan of this statement:  update table t
     set transfer_counter_column_table =: new.transfer_counter_column_view 
     where t.id =: old.id;

Comment: I am looking for a solution to intercept all client-side updates so that I can update the table below

client side update example:
update view_based_on_table set transfer_counter_column_view where id = 1;

this solution should also perform well. performing well means that the queries should be solved in less than a second.

With the trigger solution, the queries take 3–8 seconds. The performance of the trigger is not so good because I do up to 300 updates on the client side in one minute.

Comment: without having the explain plan of the update statement, I cannot help you. You have 15 indexes over the table, which I believe is a lot, but it does not matter if you run 300 updates per minutes or 10 without understanding the impact of this update in the whole operation.